# Will the "get_current_user()" function work on Linux/OSX?

Tags: php, linux, windows, macos

I just learned PHP this morning and I'm writing a simple PHP script that I am planning to use for a scheduled task everyday. The script is working perfectly fine but for some features that I want to add later on, I would like to use the get_current_user() function from.

My question is: **Is the get_current_user() cross-platform compatible?**

I'm not entirely sure because I'm still new to this scripting language. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: have you read the documentation?

Comment: It's right [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php), and the comments suggests that `get_current_user()` could in fact have platform differences (unless you're using the Wordpress function with the same name) !

Comment: @DanielA.White and adeneo, Yes I've read the documentation, and I didn't see any examples on cross-platform usage so I didn't know. The comments both suggests towards this "posix_getuid()" and I had no idea what that was up until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get_current_user does work on POSIX based systems (linux, mac, etc)

Make sure you understand what this function does. It returns the **owner** of the script (file), **not the process owner**. If the script file is owned by root, but run by user "jamie", get_current_user() will return root.

To get the process owner, use this snippet from the first comment in the [get_current_user PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php)

```
<?php
$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
print $processUser['name'];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, after looking into more (simultaneously after asking on here) I found more into and this is what I was looking for. Thank you for your help.